# Como posso adicionar dados em outra coluna com o resultado de uma outra coluna?

Tags: mysql

Estou com o seguinte cenário e preciso adicionar o resultado de um *Select* em outra coluna da mesma tabela, por exemplo, um coluna com os números e outra para verificar a frequência que esses números aparecem:

```
números|frequência
 1     | 2
 2     | 1 E assim por diante.
```

Eu consegui fazer um select que seleciona e mostra a frequência, conforme abaixo, porém não sei como fazer para adicionar o resultado que é a frequência em outra coluna, pois preciso usar os resultado dessas colunas no *HTML*.

*Select* para verificar a frequência:

```
select  distinct id, CONCAT(numeros, "frequencia",count(id)) as Numeros from tb_numeros group by numeros;
```

O resultado esta saindo assim por enquanto:

```
[{"id":1,"Numeros":"1 - frequencia - 3"},{"id":2,"Numeros":"2 - frequencia - 1"}]
```

Muito Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Pessoal, eu informei que era da mesma coluna, porém preciso que seja em outra tabela. Grato pessoal.

Answer (score 1):

Basta fazer um update com um subselect no mysql seria assim

```
UPDATE tabela1 t1 JOIN tabela2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.col1 = t2.col1, t1.col2 = t2.col2, ...
```

ou

```
   update table1 t set
column1 = (select column1 from old_table where id = t.id),
column2 = (select column2 from old_table where id = t.id);
```

veja a forma que você acha mais facil